# Unable to show calculated value in Label Box- Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, label, double

New to coding and everything seems correct but when I press calculate,

the property tax shows: "Tax is $000.00" instead of the actual calculated value.

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim txtValue As Double 'Declare variable To hold the Property value'
    Dim lblTax As Double 'to calculate the tax value'
    If Not Double.TryParse(txtValue, lblTax) Then 'check for the enter number
    Else
        lblTax = (txtValue * 0.0135) 'calculate the 1.35% of property value
        'format the results as a $ currency.
        lblTaxSolution.Text = "Tax is: " & lblTax.ToString("$0,00.00") 'display the number with formatted output
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use `$0,00.00`. Do it like this: `"Tax is: $" & lblTax.ToString("N2")"`.

Comment: Now it says, Property tax: Tax is $0.00

Comment: check the value of `txtValue`

Comment: Will do. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your textbox to "txtValue" ( there is no need to create separate variable ). Use the following snippet, and you will get the expected result.

```
Dim lblTax As Double 'to calculate the tax value'
        If Not Double.TryParse(txtValue.text, lblTax) Then 'check for the enter number
        Else
            lblTax = (txtValue.Text * 0.0135) 'calculate the 1.35% of property value
            'format the results as a $ currency.
            lblTaxSolution.Text = $"Tax is: {lblTax:$0,00.00}" 'display the number with formatted output
        End If
```